# Hyperbola locus sketched by Descartes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

D.J.Struik's  *A Concise History of Mathematics* (pp 98 4th edition) contains a sketch  I modified here (wrongly?) Variable line $GPL$ passes through a fixed point $G$ and, as a rigid right triangle $LNK$ moves on x-axis, $P$ traces out a hyperbola with Cartesian equation:

$$ y^2 = cy - (c/b) \,x \,y + a y -ac $$

Did I get it right?

EDIT1:

Original French was long winding, Struik's translation elusive (to me) with a print error.Today it goes so fast, so posted to check it out.. an oblique asymptoted hyperbola, axes tilted.

[image: DescertesHyperbola]

EDIT2:

[Subsequent to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018540/geometrical-construction-by-descartes-oblique-hyperbola)  hand sketched  3 types of tiny right triangles.

Comment: Is the triangle $LNK$ a right triangle, or it doesn't matter what kind of triangle it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see.

\begin{align*}
G &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\a\end{pmatrix} &
L &= \begin{pmatrix}t\\0\end{pmatrix} &
K &= \begin{pmatrix}t+b\\0\end{pmatrix} &
N &= \begin{pmatrix}t\\c\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
GL&:\quad & ax + ty &= at \\
KN&:\quad & cx + by &= c(t+b) \\
\end{alignat*}

\begin{equation*}
P = \frac1{ab-tc}\begin{pmatrix}
t(ab-tc-bc)\\abc
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Assuming $a,b,c\neq 0$ this means the locus of $C$ has to be

$$abc - aby - bcy + cxy + by^2 = 0$$

which is equivalent to the formula you gave. So yes, you are right.

How did I compute this? I represented my points as homogeneous coordinates, e.g. $G=[0:a:1]$. Then computing the line joining two points means computing the cross product. intersecting two lines is a cross product, too. So at that point I had $P=[P_x:P_y:P_z]$ in homogeneous coordinates. Usually one would dehomogenize this using $x=\frac{P_x}{P_z}$ but instead I kept this as a polynomial, namely $P_zx - P_x=0$, and likewise $P_zy - P_y=0$. Then I eliminated $t$ from these two polynomials using a resultant.

\begin{align*}
P_x &= t(ab-tc-bc) \\
P_y &= abc \\
P_z &= ab-tc \\
P_zx - P_x &= c t^{2} + \left(- a b + b c -  c x\right) t + a b x \\
P_zy - P_y &= - c y t -  a b c + a b y \\
0 &= \begin{vmatrix}
c & - a b + b c -  c x & a b x \\
- c y & - a b c + a b y & 0 \\
0 & - c y & - a b c + a b y
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= b \cdot a \cdot c^{2} \cdot (a b c -  a b y -  b c y + c x y + b y^{2})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

[image]

\begin{align}
   \triangle PXK \sim \triangle NLK
   &\implies \dfrac{y}{XK} = \dfrac cb \\
   &\implies XK = \dfrac bcy \\
   &\implies XL =  \dfrac bcy-b \\
\end{align}.

\begin{align}
   \triangle GYP \sim \triangle PXL
   &\implies \dfrac{a-y}{x} = \dfrac{y}{\left( \dfrac bcy-b \right)} \\
   &\implies \dfrac{a-y}{x} = \dfrac{cy}{by-bc} \\
   &\implies aby-abc-by^2+bcy = cxy \\
   &\implies by^2 = bcy -cxy +aby - abc \\
   &\implies y^2 = cy -\dfrac cb xy +ay - ac \\
\end{align}