# Geometrical construction by Descartes/ Oblique hyperbola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I wish to share verification/completion of the original construction of the oblique hyperbola by Descartes. At first I was looking at the construction of right branch only and temporarily concluded that the sketch was in error as it was not included in original. But then realized that the incomplete sketch defined one branch only. And now, I have an approximate construction to include either branch of the inclined asymptote (not shown) hyperbola. Hopefully it gives a fuller exposition to what Descrates may have had in his mind on this when he introduced co-ordinate geometry.

[image: EarlyCordGeomGraphHypb]

[HyperbolaEqunSketch_by_Descartes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015292/hyperbola-locus-sketched-by-descartes/2016436#2016436)

In the above link the equation of hyperbola has been derived using Similar triangle relations in the above original by Descartes and now by Steven Gregory and also MvG using homogeneous coordinates. A Mathematca plot with rough lines added by hand is:

```
{a, c, b} = {15, 2, 1};
slope = c/b;
cp = ContourPlot[{y (1/a + 1/c) - y^2/(a c) - x y/(a b) == 1, y == c, 
   y == -c}, {x, -10, 30}, {y, a, -10}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Thick}, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image: GLN_construction_comprehensive]

I request anyone here to please draw and upload a better sketch using Geogebra, GSP, Z.u.L with Java etc. by using *bigger* $LNK$ *generating triangle of the oblique hyperbola*... as the small moving rigid triangle generates this hyperbola as locus.

(The region for my discomfiture prompting the post could be stated only after a night's sleep! ). There are *three* regions in the plot generaton. In the region X hypotenuse line and rotating line through **G** cut **on** the moving rigid but  *tiny* triangle. In the region **A** it is **above** ( in Descrates plot)  and is **below** in region **B**. Region **A** alone he gave is insufficient to visualize  at first instance the generation of the entire plot, imho.

*In Summary,*

If a right triangle slides with its short side $b$ on a line with minimum distance $a$ from a fixed point $G$  connecting right angle vertex to it by a ray $R$,then the intersection of $R$ and hypotenuse $h$ completly defines an oblique hyperbola of axes angle $ \cot^{-1}(b/c). $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a better diagram, here's one based on a GeoGebra sketch I made while considering your earlier question.

[image]

Note the triangle $\triangle O_\star A_\star B_\star$ such that $\overline{O_\star C} \parallel \overline{AB}$. As the point ostensibly constructed where $\overleftrightarrow{O_\star C}$ meets $\overleftrightarrow{A_\star B_\star}$ is "at infinity", we may conclude that $\overleftrightarrow{A_\star B_\star}$ is actually the hyperbola's oblique asymptote.

---

**Observation.** If $\overline{OC}$ is extended to meet the oblique asymptote at, say, $D$, then $\square CDB_\star O_\star$ is a parallelogram, so that $\overline{OB} \cong \overline{CD}$. Thus, we have a general property that *if a secant line $\ell$ to a hyperbola is perpendicular to an asymptote, then the segments of $\ell$ "between" the hyperbola and the asymptotes are congruent.* As a special case: *If a tangent line at $P$ is perpendicular to an asymptote, then $P$ is the midpoint of the line segment bounded by the asymptotes.* Neat.

**Edit.** As @Narasimham comments, the bisected-tangent-segment property is true for *any* tangent. The secant-segment property is also true for secants that are not-necessarily-perpendicular to an asymptote. So, things are even neater than I first thought. :) Still, I like that the Descartes construction makes these properties nearly-obvious for lines that *are* perpendicular to the asymptotes.

Comment: Hi Blue, nice construction The oblique asymptote coincides with hypotenuse when vertex ray is parallel to the hypotenuse ray. That congruence is the basis of this construction. Could you also now please include/update with couple of more triangles for the branch below x-axis and one more case to left of y-axis where the rays cut directly?  Also please show grid line and (b,c) values. However, I disagree about the last special case comment/observation. The tangent point  * always* bisects the segment enclosed between asymptotes.of *any* hyperbola..

Comment: @Narasimham: I don't really have time to update the image to your specifications. (Besides, I'm somewhat averse to adding visual clutter with additional triangles.) You'll have to deal with it as-is, or grab your own copy of GeoGebra and simply perform the Descartes construction with as many triangles as you like. (For a complete picture of the resulting hyperbola, take any five sample points and use GeoGebra's "conic through five points" operation.)

Comment: @Narasimham: As for the bisecting observation: I didn't realize ---or maybe I just forgot--- that *any* tangent segment bounded by the asymptotes is bisected by the point of tangency. Thanks for pointing that out. As it turns out, the secant property I mention is also true for *any* secant lines, not just those perpendicular to an asymptote. I'll make a note of this in the answer.

Comment: (regarding first comment) but how?  To use "the conic through five points" option  for drawing  a hyperbola we have only three points: $ (0,a), (0,c)$ , intersection point  P of lines  $(GL , NK).$ Or did you actually mean Java dragging the *entire* $NLK$ triangle?

Comment: @Narasimham: Referring to my diagram ... You have $B$ and $C$, and you also have their reflections (not shown) in the hyperbola's center, $A_\star$. That gives four points. For a fifth, translate $\triangle OAB$ wherever you like along the horizontal, and then use Descartes' construction. No matter where that triangle is, you will (naturally) get the same hyperbola. (Of course, you could also use $B$ and $C$ and *three* points constructed from three separate translates of the $\triangle OAB$.)

Comment: OK, so all the five points are effectively results of (or artifacts of, if you will )  the same Descartes construction...

Comment: @Narasimham: Come to think of it ... Once you have the asymptotes, you can construct the hyperbola's axis as an appropriate angle bisector through $A_\star$. (GeoGebra has a convenient Angle Bisector tool.) Then, the reflections of $B$ and $C$ across this line make two more points on the curve. (The reflections of those in $A_\star$ make two *more* points.) So, you actually have a few options beyond just translating $\triangle OAB$ around.